# connection error in php from database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting this warning

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\S_WEB\connection\dbcon.php on line 14`

My table `users` is:
[image: table users with 0 rows]

My code to query `user` is:

```
<?php

     //Connect to database

      $servername = "127.0.0.1";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "root";
      $dbname = "s_web";

// Create connection


$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','root','s_web')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');



$query = "SELECT * FROM user" ;
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database');


$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo $row['username'] . ' ' . $row['password'] . '<br />';
}

?>
```

My question is that I am getting an error when I am trying to establishing a connection database using mysqli. 
there I am getting many errors. last two days I am trying to fix my problem but I didn't.

Comment: The error Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) means that the user root with password root does not have permission to connect to the database s_web. Are you sure that the username and the password root is correct and that the user root has permission to access the database s_web ?

Comment: actually i was insert username 'root' and password 'root'. and how i know user root have the permission to access the database.

Comment: Do you remember adding a password for your database.? It looks like your are using wamp server. If you don't remember adding a password during wamp setup then try with `$password = "";`

Comment: do you use tools like PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench ?

Comment: make sure your DB password is 'root'

Comment: yes i am using wamp server and i am not adding any password but my username is root and for this i already uninstall then install the wamp server. and DB password is root which i insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer :**

```
<?php

     //Connect to database

      $servername = "127.0.0.1";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "";
      $dbname = "s_web";

// Create connection


$db = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname)
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');


//as per error table user doesn't exist in the database, actual table name users
$query = "SELECT * FROM users" ;


//You're running same query twice that's why I commented one
//mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database');


$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo $row['username'] . ' ' . $row['password'] . '<br />';
}

?>
```

Comment: Still I have same problem 
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\S_WEB\connection\dbcon.php on line 13
i am not using any yes password

Comment: do you use phpmyadmin ? are you able to login in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: are you able to login in phpmyadmin? what username and password you are using ?

Comment: user name is root and password is blank

Comment: [http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142561/db-issue] click on this link for further discussion.

Comment: aaw dear i dont have 20 reputation thats why i am not able to chat with you there?

Comment: dear Touheed now i get die result  "Error querying database"

Comment: there is no line i thought this is return of die?

Comment: replace this die('Error querying database') with this die(mysqli_error($db)), and tell me what error you're getting.

Comment: Table 's_web.user' doesn't exist ... here s_web is my database name and user table name

Comment: then there is not `user` table in your `s_web` database.